# Autocomplete parentheses in vanilla JavaScript inputs

Tags: javascript

I have an input where the user can type and I want it to autocomplete parentheses, quotes, and more. E.g. if the user types `(` then after that `)` is inserted and the cursor is placed in between. How can I do this?

Comment: Sounds fine - what's your question about this?

Comment: I fixed the original question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working pretty good ...

```js
    var form = document.getElementById("input");

    form.addEventListener("keypress", function (e) {
        let text = form.value;

        var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
        // console.log(code)
        
        // ()
        if (code == 40) { 
            text += ')'
            form.value = text
            form.setSelectionRange(text.length-1, text.length-1);
        }

        // ""
        if (code == 34) {
            text += '"'
            form.value = text
            form.setSelectionRange(text.length-1, text.length-1);
        }
    });
```

```html
<textarea id="input" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
```